# Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PHFetchOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to access and delete photos in iOS. I use PHFetchOptions and PHAsset (classes) to collect latest images from iOS device. However, when I build the solution in Visual Studio 2019, I get the error message below:

"Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PHFetchOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)"

I checked the references in MyApp.iOS. Xamarin.iOS was installed in the references. I have also restarted the solution and checked in different machine.

```
var photosOptions = new PHFetchOptions();                                    
photosOptions.SortDescriptors = new NSSortDescriptor[] { new 
NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false) };                                                                   
var photo = PHAsset.FetchAssets(photosOptions.fetchLimit = 1);                                   
var filePath = photo.Path;                                   
System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
```

I would like to know if I miss any libraries or references for iOS photo manipulation or if there is an issue with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Tried using the `PhotoKit`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/photokit

Comment: What do you mean before it works ( like in Visual Studio 2017)?

Comment: Using Photos namespace fixed the issue. Thanks